# How to solve AzureFile mount error(22): Invalid argument inside container?

Tags: kubernetes, mount, azure-aks, azure-files

I've got an error on mounting AzureFile Share inside AKS(1.18.2) container (build on top of Ubuntu 18.04 with cifs-utils installed):

```
Warning  FailedMount  0s  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-37397744-vmss000001  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "myapplication-logs" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: systemd-run
Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5e19e1d0-0bfd-4760-a87a-00cb0f3e573a/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/crawler-logs --scope -- mount -t cifs -o file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,vers=3.0,<masked> //myazurestorage.file.core.windows.net/crawler-logs /var/lib/kubelet/pods/5e19e1d0-0bfd-4760-a87a-00cb0f3e573a/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/myapplication-logs
Output: Running scope as unit run-r403b463e326d4562a7e44dc8fe018b4b.scope.
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Here is my yaml config:

```
    kind: StorageClass
    apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: myapplication-logs
    provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
    reclaimPolicy: Retain
    allowVolumeExpansion: true
    parameters:
      skuName: Standard_LRS
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: myapplication-logs
    spec:
      capacity:
        storage: 3Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
      storageClassName: myapplication-logs
      azureFile:
        secretName: azurefilesharesecretname}
        shareName: myapplication-logs
        readOnly: false
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: myapplication-logs
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
      storageClassName: myapplication-logs
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 3Gi
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: myapplication
      replicas: 1
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            name: myapplication
            readinessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /probes/ready
                port: 5000
              timeoutSeconds: 60
              periodSeconds: 10
            ports:
            - containerPort: 21602
            - containerPort: 5000
            livenessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /probes/healthy
                port: 5000
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
              periodSeconds: 10
              timeoutSeconds: 30
            image: myappacr.azurecr.io/myapplication:1.0.391
            volumeMounts:
            - readOnly: true
              name: secrets-volume
              mountPath: /usr/bin/myapp/Secrets
            - name: configuration-volume
              mountPath: /usr/bin/myapp/Configuration
            - name: myapplication-logs
              mountPath: /usr/bin/myapp/logs
    
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: acr-dev-regcred
          volumes:
          - name: secrets-volume
            secret:
              secretName: myapplication-secrets
          - configMap:
              name: myapplication-configuration
            name: configuration-volume
          - name: myapplication-logs
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: myapplication-logs
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: myapplication
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: myapplication-deployment
      labels:
        app: myapplication
```

StorageClass, PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim is successfully deployd without any errors\events.

Cannot find out where is the problem?
Any ideas on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to consume azure file share as volume from a container in AKS

1. Manually create and use a volume with Azure Files share. Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume)

In this case the PV need to specify `mountOptions`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: azurefile
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: aksshare
    readOnly: false
  mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - nobrl
```

2. Dynamically create and use a persistent volume with Azure Files. Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-dynamic-pv)

In this case StorageClass need to have `mountOptions`

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

Now looking at your yamls It seems you are mixing the manual and dynamic mode because you are creating both `PersistentVolume` and a `StorageClass`. I suggest to follow one of the suitable approach and have `mountOptions` specified properly which is mandatory for both the modes.

Comment: I tried many ways - first of all of course it was Microsoft Documentation from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume
Only dynamic works - but I need static instead.
The reason I create my own StorageClass is because of some parameters:
```
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
```

Comment: The doc shows mountoptions in PersistentVolume..did you try with it?

Comment: Yes shure! All combinations - with mount options and without.

Comment: Also I assume that those mountOptions are default now in kubernetes version 1.18.2 - at least the Error shows all the arguments - and there are same arguments as in mountOptions

Comment: Have you checked this https://askubuntu.com/questions/427044/mounting-cifs-drive-gives-mount-error22-invalid-argument

Comment: You mean I have to set SMB protocol version for cifs?

Comment: No luck. Same error, although I can see mount option vers applied:
mount -t cifs -o dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,gid=1000,mfsymlinks,nobrl,uid=1000,vers=2.1

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
There was a problem with secret I created.
It was created with kubectl apply -f secret.json and accountstoragekey wasn't encoded in base64.

Thanx to Azure Support!